# Is it possible to manage Multiple Custom Fields with Some Relations

Tags: custom-field

It is hard to explain my question, so I will try to explain with an example.

Note : I take YouTube as just an example.

**What's I am going to do** : I need to save / display a few YouTube videos for each each posts.

So I have three custom fields.

1. youtube_url
2. youtube_title
3. small_description_about_video

I can create above custom fields and can create fronted form to get those details from fronted too. No problem at all....

**What is the problem** : I need to repeat the above group. And It should be identify that which youtube_url belongs to which youtube_title, etc.....

Can it possible with WordPress Custom Fileds?

Comment: 1 video per post or more??

Comment: @PiyushRawat More.... That is the my problem... And count will change for each each post. For some posts there is no.. some post 1, some post 2, and even some post 20]

Comment: using a plugin?

Comment: What I understand is to have multiple entries for the videos and chain them with `post id` so you can read the `id` and meta values from the `wp_postmeta` table